How may a twice-born atone for eating an egg unknowingly?
This answer says Rig Veda has a verse which prays to destroy egg eaters.

So if a twice born are egg knowingly or unknowingly, what are all the
atonements shall be done?

Whether egg is consumable for non dwijas or Shudras?


